# How can we use @RabbitListener and @JMSListener alternatively based on env?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-jms, azure-servicebus-queues

Actually, I have on premises spring boot application which consumes rabbitMQ messages using @RabbitListener and I have migrated the same application to azure which consumes AzureServiceBus messages using @JMSListener.

We are maintaining same code for both on premises and Azure . So, because of these two listeners, I'm planning to replicate the same consumer code in two different classes with same content with two different Listeners

**consumer with JMSListener:**

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue}", concurrency = "${threads}", containerFactory = "defaultContainer")
public Message processMessage(@Payload final String message) {
    //do stuff with same content
}
```

**consumer with RabbitListener:**

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = "${app.rabbitmq.queue}") 
public Message processMessage(@Payload final String message) {
    //do stuff with same content
}
```

Is there any possibility of avoiding the duplicate code in two classes  ?  How can we handle listeners on a fly with only one consumer? Can any one please suggest me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add both annotations to the same method with the `autoStartup` property set according to which Spring profile is active.

For `@RabbitListener` there is an `autoStartup` property on the annotation itself but, in both cases, there are Spring Boot properties `auto-startup` to control whether the container starts or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion Russell. Can't we avoid using these two annotations and make use of MessageListenerAdapters accordingly for RabbitMQ and ASB ? so that we can use only one consumer . I've gone through this link for RabbitMQ https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/springboot-rabbitmq-example .

Comment: Yes, you can do it programmatically, but each annotation builds a different type of `MessageListenerAdapter` so you would be replicating the framework code; using the annotations mean you don't have to write any code.

Comment: Thanks Russell. Can you please provide some articles for autoStartup property ?

Comment: Simply set `autoStartup=false` on the listener container factory - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated-support